# Do not record from <b-form-select> to my database

Tags: django, vuejs2

how I hope you can help me, I am trying to save the values ​​that are in a b-form-select, the funny thing is that it fills the select and as you can see I do alert, and there I realize that if it brings the value that I need , but when making the put puts a null value, inside my model I define it as charfield and it takes it from a Choice

```
<b-form-select v-model="elmovimiento.tipo" @select="Tselected" :options="Toptions" required="required"></b-form-select>



updateMovimiento: function() {

            alert("Este es Tipo: "+this.elmovimiento.tipo+" Este es Descripción: "+this.elmovimiento.descripcion);              
            id = this.elmovimiento.id;              
            varurl = "/control/movimiento/api/mov/"+id+'/';
            this.$http.put(varurl, this.elmovimiento).then((response) => {
                alert("Este es Tipo: "+this.elmovimiento.tipo+" Este es Descripción: "+this.elmovimiento.descripcion+" Otro: "+this.elmovimiento.arete);
                this.elmovimiento = response.data;
                this.$root.$emit('bv::hide::modal', this.infoModal.id);
                })
            .catch((err) => {
                this.loading = false;
                console.log(err);
            })
        },
```

Comment: Try to pass value inside your function()

Comment: I do not understand how?